What is the best test to run to compare presence/absence of something between sampling locations?
I have data on the presence/absence of four different pathogens found in edible crabs in 7 locations over 2 seasons. For this study, 30 crabs were collected from each site and for each crab the presence or absence of each pathogen was recorded. I want to know if the total frequency of each pathogen differs between the 7 sites but I am unsure how to analyse this. What test or model must I run on this data to achieve this? Can I perform a binomial ANOVA or can I use a Chi-Square test? Or do I use a generalised linear model with a binomial distribution? The data look a bit like this except there are 60 samples from each site instead of 5 (0 = absent, 1 = present):


30 crabs or 60 samples from each site?

30 crabs from each site x 2 so 60 in total from each site.

Where does the x2 come from? Are you assessing each individual twice? If so, could there be a time effect between the two measurements?

I'm collecting crabs from each site twice

I see two possibilities:

A separate logistical regression per pathogen, with site as a predictor.
A large model with both pathogen and site as predictors. In this case, you should account for the repeated measurements on each individual, e.g., by running a generalized linear mixed model (GLMM), with a binomial family, a logistic link function, and a random intercept per individual.

The second approach is probably a little more realistic, since I would naively assume that the presence of one pathogen makes the presence of another one more likely, which approach 1 would not account for. But it also depends on how much statistics you and your readers are comfortable with.

I have already run a GLMM on the data using the site as a random variable and Sex, Season and Size as fixed factors. The model looked like this:
glm(Digenea ~ Width + Sex + Season + (1 | Site)
Am I correct in assuming the intercept in this model when I get the summary output is the effect of Site?

I think so, but am not overly familiar with it.
